# Not equals in mongo mapper

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

I'm trying to run a query where I want to ignore records with a certain email address...

@foo = Bar.all(:email => 'xxx')  <--- Except I want to negate where this email address exists.

Please let me know how I can do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Or

`@foo = Bar.all(:email.ne => 'xxx')`

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
@foo = Bar.all(:email => {"$ne" => "xxx"})
```

Answer (score 0):

@foo = Bar.all(:email => {"$ne" => "xxx"})