# Ruby / MongoDB : Exclude certain results in Find

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm typically using:

```
@coll.find({"lang"=>@language,"description"=>@description,"location"=>@location},{:limit=>@results_needed}).to_a
```

But there are times when I have an array of "_ids", that I don't want to be included in the results. Is there a native way to do that? I've been doing a hack with `.delete_if` but I would like to keep the database doing as much work as possible.

Comment: which driver/mapper are you using?

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
@coll.find(:id.ne => array_of_ids)
```

or

```
@coll.find(:id => {:$ne => array_of_ids})
```

From [Not equals in mongo mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541528/not-equals-in-mongo-mapper).

Comment: `:$ne` is a valid symbol if the string version bothers you.